# Split a table into three rows

Tags: php, html-table

I've got a PHP page, some of which is something like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

    echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>C1</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['C1'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

How can I change this so the table goes C1 C1 C1?

So if I have the following set of values - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - the table returns the following

C1 C1 C1

1  2  3

4  5  6

7  8  9

How can I do this?

Comment: A quick note: I see you're using `mysql_` functions. This family of functions are deprecated in PHP, and will not be available in future versions. It is strongly recommended that new code begin using non-deprecated API for database access, like `mysqli` or PDO. Please see the documentation for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: True - thanks for that - hadn't seen it. This is an old page I'm updating...

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
$cpt=1;
echo "<tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
{
  echo "<td>" . $row['C1'] . "</td>";
  if ($cpt%3==0)
    echo "</tr><tr>";
  $cpt++;
}
echo "</tr>";
```

will create a new row after every 3 result

Answer (score 1):

Define in `$N` how many cols you want.

```
$N=3;
$col=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
{
    $col++;
    if ($col==1) echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['C1'] . "</td>";
    if ($col==$N)
    {
        $col=0;
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
if ($col>0) //if there is an open <tr>...
    echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) { 
  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr><th>C1</th><th>C1</th><th>C1</th></tr>";

  $col = 0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
    if ($col == 0) { echo "<tr>"; }
    echo "<td>" . $row['C1'] . "</td>";
    if ($col == 2) { echo "</tr>"; }
    $col = ($col + 1) % 3
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also Working (little bit short one)

```
$a=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
{
echo "<td>".$row['c1']."</td>".(($a%3==0)?'</tr><tr>':'');
$a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
     <th>C1</th><th>C1</th><th>C1</th>";

$x = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
{
   if ($x % 3 == 0) {
     echo "</tr><tr>";
   }
   echo "<td>" . $row['C1'] . "</td>";
   $x++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

I assume you have just 3 columns and count of your result is submultiple of 3
pay attention to `</tr><tr>`

Answer (score 0):

No test so it might be some syntax error but you can do something like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>C1</th>
    <th>C1</th>
    <th>C1</th>
    </tr><tr>";
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
    {
        if ($i == 2) {
            $i = 0;
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo "<td>" . $row['C1'] . "</td>";
        $i++;
    }
    if ($i > 0) {
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```